Disbable color scheme in neovim
I've just upgraded my fedora installation and I suppose neovim was also upgraded. Anyway, before the upgrade I had the same colors in neovim as in my terminal: green font on a black background. After the upgrade that changed to white font on a pale black background (in neovim; my terminal still looks the same).
I can only assume that neovim introduced some sort of default color scheme in the new version. How can I disable that?
vim still looks the same btw.

Welcome to [vi.se]! Yes Neovim introduced a new theme in version 0.10, you can go back to the old theme using :colorscheme vim, can you check whether that does what you want? If so I'd be happy to post it as an answer.

Yes, thanks, that works. But how to correctly define this in init.vim? I tried set colorscheme=vim, but that gave me an error.

Found it: It's just colorscheme vim in init.vim.

Neovim 0.10 introduced a new default colorscheme.
You can still access the old color scheme under the name vim.
In order to configure that in your initialization files, you can use the following in init.lua:
if vim.fn.has('nvim-0.10') > 0 then
  vim.cmd.colorscheme('vim')
end

Or the following in init.vim:
if has('nvim-0.10')
  colorscheme vim
endif

These snippets will only try to use the vim colorscheme under Neovim 0.10 or later, where vim is a valid choice (the command would raise an error under older Neovim or classic Vim.)
